How to add adornments postfix to Maui xaml enty element?
I would like to add adornments postfix to my Maui entry as "test" shows, how is it possible?


You can try to custom the control.

Do you mean like wrapping into a frame with entry and label?






Yes, that's what I mean.

You can custom a such control by yourself.
The custom control(you can declare it as a contentview):
<Border BackgroundColor="LightBlue">
    <Border.StrokeShape>
        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="40"/>
    </Border.StrokeShape>
    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="8*,2*" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
        <Entry BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Label Text="test" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>

And then disable the entry's underline and border:
For the android and ios, add the following code in the App.cs's constructor:
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("NoBorder", (h, v) =>
            {
#if ANDROID
                h.PlatformView.BackgroundTintList = Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
#elif IOS
                h.PlatformView.BorderStyle = UIKit.UITextBorderStyle.None;
#endif
            });

And for the windows platform, add the following code in the App.xaml below the Platforms/Windows folder.
 <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThickness">0</Thickness>
        <Thickness x:Key="TextControlBorderThemeThicknessFocused">0</Thickness>
    </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>

